# Break down XIRR to different segments

Tags: equities

Currently, I have the following transactions.

```
01/01/2000 I used $1000 to purchase stocks
30/05/2000 I received $100 stock dividend.
31/12/2000 I sold all stocks for $2000.
```

Hence, if I use XIRR to calculate

```
01/01/2000  -1000 (Invest in stock)
30/05/2000  100 (Received dividend)
31/12/2000  2000 (Sales in stock)
```

My yearly return is **1.157284223** (115.73%)

From the above calculated XIRR, may I know how much % does the received dividend contribute to the total XIRR? Is there any proper formula to calculate so?

I wish to get x & y figure.

> I am having annualized return 115.73%. Out of this 115.73% annualized
>   return, x% is contributed by dividend gain, y% is contributed by stock
>   sales.

The reason I ask so, as I'm currently building a portfolio performance chart.

[image]

I need to break down my yearly XIRR to different segments (dividend, sales gain, paper gain)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but does the following work?

Dividend gain:

-1000 purchase 
  100 dividend
 1000 sell (ignoring sell profit)

Sell profit:
-1000 purchase 
 2000 sell

Comment: I tested using [01/01/2000, 31/12/2000, 30/05/2000] with [-1000, 1000, 100], it gives 0.10 (10%)? Should I expect 15.73%?

Comment: Yes it only would work out if both dividend and sale happens on 31/12/2000

I'll have to think some more on this.

Comment: Actually looking at it a bit more, if I change the end sell value to 4000 I'm getting 3.234.

Comment: doing some more examples

only dividend profit:
    -1000
      100
     1000
=> 0.1061

your example:
    -1000
      100
     2000
=> 1.1572

Comment: doing some more examples

a) only dividend profit:
    -1000
      100
     1000
=> 0.1061

b) your example:
    -1000
      100
     2000
=> 1.1572

c) double sell profit:
    -1000
      100
     4000
=> 3.2340


as I didn't change the dividend, shouldn't the dividend profit always be the same (0.1061)?

Which would mean that the sales account for 

a) 0
b) 1.0511
c) 3.1279

of profit

Comment: doing the same examples without interest results in a) only dividend profit: -1000 1000 => 0 b) your example: -1000 2000 => 1 c) double sell profit: -1000 4000 => 3
so to be honest I'm not sure where the remaining percentage should be put into, it's a) 0, b) 0.0511, c) 0.1279 and it's depending on both the dividend and the sell profit at the end.

Comment: After some thoughts, I think it might not possible to break down XIRR to different segments. Consider we're having -ve in sales gain, and +ve in received dividend. Let's say we have a +ve XIRR for received dividend combined with sales gain. It seems that doesn't make sense, to have a -ve segments (sales gain), as one of the components in XIRR.

Answer (score 0):

You use 4 number (dividend/investment at first date, sales/investment at second date) to build one number.

There is an infinite number of possibilities to obtain a given results so no you can't give the dividend part with only XIRR.

If you have the investments/dividends/sales/dates well you can remove the sales and use only the dividends if you want the dividends part.